# AC and DC-coupled amplifiers in parallel

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I am curious of the effects of a circuit setup like this, with a AC-coupled (capacitors before inputs) and a DC-coupled (no capacitors) amplifier measuring a potential difference in parallel.

Surprisingly, I was not able to find much information online about this type of setup. (Note that in the picture I have an an instrumentation amplifier for generality, but the same question could also apply to op-amps with feedback.)

[image]

Comment: What would be the point of the experiment? One amp is DC coupled and the other AC coupled. Depending on input impedance, the cutoff frequency is dependent on that, and with nothing to keep the common mode voltage in sane limits, leakage can throw off the readings.

Comment: The system I want to measure would ideally be measured with just the DC amp, however the measurement interface inevitably suffers from unpredictable DC drift at the interface. Because of this, I want to also measure the AC coupled signal, as I know that the signal I'm measuring is also technically periodic.  The idea is that both signals being measured could be analyzed to assess the system being measured. Maybe it doesn't work, but it's worth a try in my opinion. 

Could you explain further what you mean by keeping the common mode voltage in sane limits?

Comment: What DC drift? Your DC amp must be able to measure it anyway. Perhaps if you asked a question about what you have and how to measure it, as it curretly sounds like an X-Y problem, where you are trying to implement Y to do X, but Y might not be what you should ask.

Comment: The V+/V- inputs will physically develop oxide layers throughout the implementation, which will randomly bias the voltage sent in through each input. Technically the AC inputs would be biased as well, but not at the frequencies I am interested in. My question is based around the effects of having these capacitors in parallel. In my setup, I know the DC setup works; I know the AC setup works; however only measuring one of these will not tell me the full story.

Answer (score 1):

This setup is commonly used when you want an amplifier channel that will support good accuracy at DC, out to wide bandwidth, with modest flatness, for instance an oscilloscope input. It's often cheaper to use two amplifiers specified for precision and bandwidth separately, than design one which will do both.

Comment: Thanks for giving me a direction to look in. Do you know how the capacitors affect the DC amp?